# Open Ace.js code editor and select content on click

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I have a page containing multiple instances of [ace.js](https://ace.c9.io/) editors, all on read-only, displaying code.

[image]

I wish to open the editor like so and highlight its content to allow my user to easily copy it, like so:

[image]

My current approach does not show the wanted result, it does open an editor with the code inside of it BUT its height is not at the size of its content:
[image]

Heres's how I do it:

```js
function openCodeEditor(event, domElement, language) {
  event.preventDefault();

  getInstance().then((ace) => {
    ace.edit(domElement, {
      mode: `ace/mode/${language}`,
      theme: 'ace/theme/monokai',
      startLineNumber: 1,
      trim: true,
    });
  });
}

// STARTS HERE
// Called on page load to highlight each block of code
function syntaxHighlight(domElement, language, showGutter) { 
  return getInstance().then((ace) => {
    ace.require('ace/ext/static_highlight')(domElement, {
      mode: `ace/mode/${language}`,
      theme: 'ace/theme/monokai',
      startLineNumber: 1,
      showGutter,
      trim: true,
    });

    // Catch clicks here, and open the editor for selection
    domElement.addEventListener('click', (event) =>
      openCodeEditor(event, domElement, language)
    );
  });
}
```

Does anyone of you have recommendations or perhaps my approach is faulty?

Thank you !

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the height of editor to be same as the height of replaced element.

```
    var editor = ace.edit(null, {
      value: domElement.textContent,
      theme: 'ace/theme/monokai',
      mode: `ace/mode/${language}`,
    });
    editor.container.style.height = domElement.clientHeight + "px"
    domElement.replaceWith(editor.container)
```

but if the goal is simply to allow copying, selecting contents of domElement should work too.

Comment: This is a great approach, I managed to make it work by removing the `value:` in the options and using `editor.session.setValue(domElement.textContent);`. There are a couple more issues tho: options (theme and mode) don't seem to be taken into account and I need to find a way to select the content of the editor. I'll think about it and validate your answer if I'm stuck for too long. Thank you !

Comment: use `editor.selectAll()` to select the contents, i can help to debug the mode and theme issue if you can give me a page where it happens.

Comment: Seems like bumping my ace's version to a more recent one fixed the options issue. And selectAll() was what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for your help ! Now to find a way to display back the old editor when the user focuses out of the textfield created by the new one

Comment: Save the domElement and do `editor.container.replaceWith(domElement)`, and don't forget to call `editor.destroy()` on editors you don't need anymore.